# Get number of occurences from an array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to count the number of times a specific value occurs in an array in Laravel PHP

I have tried it like this

```
$posts = RedditPosts::where('search_identifier', $search_id)->get();

        $sentimentPost = array_count_values($posts->sentiment);

        dd($sentimentPost);
```

and I get this error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$sentiment
```

I have a field in my table called 'sentiment' and it is either positive, neutral or negative.

What I want to do is find out if the overall sentiment for each of the objects is positive, neutral or negative and parse that variable to a view where it can be displayed.

So basically I want to count how many times the positve, negative and neutral comes up from the results so I can compare them to one another and find out if the overall sentiment is positve, negative or neutral. In the DB i have many columns, i.e post, sentiment etc.

array_count_values is the closest thing I have found to be able to do this. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want, an approach to this problem would be:

```
$sentiments = [
              'positive' => 0,
              'neutral'  => 0,
              'negative' => 0,
            ];

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $sentiments[$post->sentiment]++;
}

dd($sentiments);
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 7):

Simply call the collection's `count` method:

```php
$count = $posts->count();
```

If all you need is the count, you can do it directly in the database:

```php
$count = RedditPosts::where('search_identifier', $search_id)->count();
```

---

If you want the count per sentiment, you can group by sentiment, then map the values to their count:

```php
$counts = $posts->groupBy('sentiment')->map->count();
```

...which will give you the count for each sentiment:

```php
dd($counts->all()); // ['positive' => 4, 'negative' => 2, 'neutral' => 9]
```

---

Alternatively, you can do all of the grouping and counting directly in the database:

```php
RedditPosts::where('search_identifier', $search_id)
           ->selectRaw('sentiment, COUNT(*) as count')
           ->groupBy('sentiment')
           ->pluck('count', 'sentiment');
```

...which will return the same associative array as the code above.